# I am getting Mailcore. sendMail() is undefined error

Tags: react-native

In my app i have one component for contact us so to send email to the company i am using react-native-mailcore library for that i have followed https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mailcore this procedure. But i am getting error MailCore.sendMail() is undefined i have have checked the procedure many times

to understand my problem i am adding some code

```
MailCore.sendMail({
  hostname: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  username: 'email',
  password: 'myPassword',
  from: {
    addressWithDisplayName: 'From Codism',
    mailbox: 'email'
  },
  to: {
    addressWithDisplayName: 'To Codism',
    mailbox: 'email'
  },
  subject: 'Testing RN MailCore' + new Date(),
  htmlBody: `<h1> How is it going </h1>
            <p> Test message </p>
          `
})
  .then(result => {
    alert(result.status);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    alert(error);
  });
```

Comment: Is this an expo project?

Comment: no its not on expo

Comment: Please reply if anyone know about this